# Request made using wrong protocol hangs indefinitely in express js

Tags: node.js, ssl, express

Consider the following.

```
let bluebird = require('bluebird');
let fs = bluebird.promisifyAll(require('fs'));
let express = require('express');
let https = require('https');
let app = express();

let eventualKeys = bluebird.all(['key', 'crt'].map(x => fs.readFileAsync("server." + x)));
let eventualCredentials = eventualKeys.then(([key, cert]) => {
  return {key: key, cert: cert};
});
let eventualHttpsServer = eventualCredentials.then(credentials => https.createServer(credentials, app));
eventualHttpsServer.then(httpsServer => httpsServer.listen(4443));
```

If I make a request to the server using https, everything works fine.

However if I make a request using http, it hangs indefinitely.

Obviously as it is an https server, it can't be expected to handle http requests. But is there a cleaner way of handling this? For instance, nginx replies to attempts to query the https port using http with a much less confusing "The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port" message.

Also is this behavior likely to cause a resource leak on the server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This hangs because the express server is not responding to the client (because it is not listening to the port).   As the server is not handling the request it will not cause a resource leak on the server,  and the client is waiting as long as it can to give the server a chance to respond.

You could set up another server listening on the http port (80) to respond with a failure or a redirect (301) if you want to handle this kind of response.  However if you are using nginx or apache it is recommended that you handle any such refusals or redirects with them,  as they are less resource intensive than starting up a new node http instance just to drop a connection.

Comment: `it is not listening to the port` - it is from a tcp point of view!

Comment: @GeorgeSimms I have clarified - the express server